# How would I ship a binary that spawns a process in a container?

Tags: docker, containers

I'm curious if there's an established set of guidelines and tools to ship a binary that spawns a process in a container.

By this, I don't mean the program makes an `exec` call to an externalized dependency, such as `Docker`. But instead, I mean actually contains the containerization technology within itself.

How could I do this? Is this done commonly? Should it be?

Note: I can see container-in-container situations being an obstacle.

Comment: What is the use case for this? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @AAron Restriction of resources and virtualization of compute for a process spawned in a desktop application.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to build your own personal docker?

Comment: @BrandonPiña Not sure. I would be happy to use Docker as the containerization technology. But, I would want it to ship with my binary. As far as the Docker desktop app is concerned, yes, if the way it starts containers does not depend on calling the externalized executable; no, if it does.

Comment: Why do you want to isolate your application from the rest of the system? If you don't have a good reason to do so, then I suggest you stick with shipping your binary without and if it needs to be containerized use a well known containerization platform like docker

Comment: I don't want to isolate the entire application necessarily. But, there is a network- and disk-intensive process that I think would benefit from a restriction of resources and perhaps a reduced attack surface via virtualization.

Comment: The Docker daemon itself is a system-level component, and (at least on Linux) access to it grants unrestricted administrator-level access over the entire host.  Unless you had some sort of "appliance" I'd have some significant concerns about this being bundled into the application.  You might look into lighter-weight approaches to limiting the application's memory use, with traditional Unix ulimit(1) as a starting point.